# App resource theme and resource externalization

Tags: android, image, resources, themes, drawable

What's a good way of doing an application specific theme package?

Background: 
Let's say my main app has functions to uses resources that are externalized in another app. This resource app has no launch icon and has a blank slate activity. The beef of this app is to contains images that allow customization in the main app when download separately. If main app doesn't find install resource app, it will use default images; but when there is a resource app installed, main app will show an option to use images from resource app.

Do I make the resource app a "library" project and reference it from main app's manifest with "uses-library" tag with required attribute set to false?

I have some success with resource app being just plain android project. I can read in images from resource app when installing from eclipse IDE. However, when I use a build script to build one of many iteration of main app, the main app doesn't see the resource app when I query for it. What could I be doing wrong here with regarding to building from script vs from IDE?